# Dynamically Change Color of notice in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a login page that consists of a form where a user enters an email and password. I check if the email and password match an entry in active record and if it does i have a notice say "Signed In" which is green by default but I have another notice about an invalid login and I am having trouble with how to go about making that notice red instead of green.

Here is my login index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Please Login</h1>
<%= form_for(:user, :url => { :action => "login" }) do |form|  %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email'%>
    <br><br>
    <%= form.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password'%>
    <br><br>
    <%= form.submit 'Login' %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", home_index_path %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my login_controller.rb

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login

    email = params[:user][:email]
    password = params[:user][:password]

    @user = User.find_by(email: email, password: password)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.try(:id)
        format.html { redirect_to login_index_path, notice: 'Signed In'}
      else
        format.html { redirect_to login_index_path, notice: 'Invalid username/password combination' }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

just change in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user
    format.html { redirect_to login_index_path, notice: 'Signed In'}
  else
    format.html { redirect_to login_index_path, alert: 'Invalid username/password combination' }
  end
end
```

Change key `notice` to `alert` in case user is not found will change the color :D